# How to mix normal model with @freezed model?

Tags: flutter, flutter-freezed

I want to create `CategoryModel` which has two fields `categoryName` and `items`, categoryName is a String field but items are `List<CategoryItem> items` and CategoryItem depends on freezed code generation while CategoryModel is not.

the following is my models:

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
part 'category_model.freezed.dart';
part 'category_model.g.dart';

class CategoryModel {
  const CategoryModel({
    required String categoryName,
    required List<CategoryItem> items,
  });
  factory CategoryModel.fromJson(
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> list, String categoryName) {
    return CategoryModel(
      categoryName: categoryName,
      items: list.map((json) => CategoryItem.fromJson(json)).toList(),
    );
  }
}

@freezed
class CategoryItem with _$CategoryItem {
  const factory CategoryItem({
    required String description,
    required int price,
    @JsonKey(name: 'img_url') required String imgUrl,
  }) = _CategoryItem;
  factory CategoryItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CategoryItemFromJson(json);
}
```

now when using I did like this:

```
final categories = supermarketCategories.entries.map((e) {
      return CategoryModel.fromJson(
        List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(e.value),
        e.key,
      );
    }).toList();
```

and in ui I want to access like this:

```
data.item2.first.categoryName
```

and

```
data.item2.first.items
```

but I got an error saying:

> The getter 'categoryName' isn't defined for the type 'CategoryModel'.
> Try importing the library that defines 'categoryName', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'categoryName'.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: just for knowing , why are you doing this way , you can covert first model to frezzed model so you can use both model in anywhere you want

Comment: I tried to make all freezed but didnt work that way, this is final supermarket = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('supermarkets')
        .doc(documentId)
        .get(); how I get the data.

Answer (score 1):

Well, right now you are trying to create your CategoryModel without a system or a property to access data.

Can you try changing CategoryModel to below and try again?

```
class CategoryModel {
  const CategoryModel({
    required this.categoryName,
    required this.items,
  });
  final String categoryName;
  final List<CategoryItem> items;
  factory CategoryModel.fromJson(
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> list, String categoryName) {
    return CategoryModel(
      categoryName: categoryName,
      items: list.map((json) => CategoryItem.fromJson(json)).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I defined the properties inside the constructor because I was using freezed before and then I refactored to not use freezed and forgot to define the fields in the class, thanks @salihgueler for noticing that.